# iOS5 using ARC: Implicit conversion of int to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

i´m using ARC to update my old project.
I have a "Filehelper" class in which i use c-functions e.g. for methods i need in almost every projects. (eg.load plist, etc..)

ViewController

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = getDictionaryFromPlistWithName(@"TestFile", @"plist");
```

Filehelper.m

```
#pragma Returns content of plist as NSDictionary
NSDictionary* getDictionaryFromPlistWithName(NSString* fileName, NSString* pathExtension) {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:pathExtension];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];

    if(fileExists){
        NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        return dictionary;
    }
    else{
        [NSException raise:@"File not found" format:@"path %@", path];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> *error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSDictionary *' is disallowed with ARC*

Any ideas how to fix it to use it with iOS 5? 
I´ve read something that i need to use (__bridge NSDictionary*), but that didn´t help.

PS.
What´s your workflow for classes which you already need? Use C-functions, too?=
What´s the best way?

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: why are you using C-style declaration of function `NSDictionary* getDictionaryFromPlistWithName(NSString* fileName, NSString* pathExtension)` instead of declaring Objective-C method like `- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryFromPlistWithName:(NSString *) fileName extension:(NSString *) pathExtension`?

Comment: @AndreyZ. because maybe he wants this to be a C function and not necessarily attached to a specific class?

Comment: Is there any other warning, e.g. about the function definition not being found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem here is that you forgot to `#include` your header file. I bet there are further warnings that you're ignoring, particularly one that says something like "unknown signature for getDictionaryFromPlistWithName, assuming it returns int". Read through your warnings and never ignore them (I strongly recommend -Werror for all ObjC projects).

Comment: Thanks, Rob. But there´s no warning. I don´t ignoring them. But thanks for your hints.

Comment: But now it works. Maybe it was just that i forgot to include the header like you said. My fault ;) Thanks all.